# Is it recommended to programmatically reload the page to clear the redux state?

Tags: redux, react-redux, next.js

I am experiencing some issues with redux. Indeed, I am using Next.js and when i'm navigating between pages i need to clear the redux state each time the url change. I did multiple things to force redux to clear but unfortunately i don't know why, maybe some asynchronous problems, my app turns mad each time the url changes and redux state is still there inside some components.

However when i reload programmatically the page with `location.reload`, everything is perfect but i am wondering if it doesn't affect performances ?

What do you think ? Should i keep doing this ?

Comment: I'd say if you're unable to clear the redux state (and I wonder how necessary that is in most circumstances) there's an underlying problem with how you're using redux--it should be pretty simple to do.

Comment: Seems like a problem specific to your app. If you post a minimal, complete and verifiable example, with a description of the expected behavior and the actual behavior, I bet someone will be able to help you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks guy , i've fixed it. That was because i set redux state in router event handler just before changing the route. I don't know why but it messed the redux state up.